# How to use "<" comparison operator in an AngularJS ng-hide call without breaking the HTML

Tags: angularjs

I am making a simple MVC w/ AngularJS app that displays a list of information and allows the user to filter what items are shown based on different criteria (the filtering is managed by Angular).

The problem I am having is that one of the ways I want to filter involves a `<=` comparison, and the `<` part of that operator is breaking the HTML code surrounding the Angular statements.

Here is the code without the `<=` :

```
<div class="rows" ng-init="init(@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))">

    <div class="column" ng-repeat="item in data" ng-hide="(!displayREI && item.TaskType == 'REI')">

        //display item contents

    </div> 

</div>
```

Here is the code with the `<=` that breaks the statement by trying to open an html tag or something

```
<div class="rows" ng-init="init(@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))">

    <div class="column" ng-repeat="item in data" ng-hide="(!displayREI && item.TaskType == 'REI') ||
                                                          !(item.dueDate <= offSetChoice)">

        //display item contents

    </div> 

</div>
```

Is there a way to use the `<` `<=` `>=` or `>` operators in a call to an Angular directive like `ng-hide` without breaking the HTML surrounding it?

Comment: Just keep your comparators inside a string. You can't make a multiline string with double-quoted strings.

Comment: Could you please try `item.dueDate == offSetChoice` instead of `item.dueDate <= offSetChoice`? Because I don't know this issue related with those operators. It may related with your data.

Comment: @RameshRajendran the == works. I'm certain the issues is that it's breaking the statement. with == https://i.imgur.com/ECWh9of.png         with <= https://i.imgur.com/o3liJ2g.png

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know this issue related with those operators.I guess the problem may related with your data. because those `<` operators does not works with `string` value

May be your `dueDate / offSetChoice` has a string values instead of date time value.

try this

Use this method for convert string to date

```
$scope.parseDatevalue= function(dateValue) {
   return Date.parse(dateValue);// the datevalue should be a date formatted string 
}
```

and your html should be looks like

```
<div class="column" ng-repeat="item in data" ng-hide="(!displayREI && 
item.TaskType == 'REI') ||!(parseDatevalue(item.dueDate) <= parseDatevalue(offSetChoice))">
   //display item contents
</div>
```

Comment: I am 100% confident the types are just ints. The names are misleading, I apologize. The images I posted to your comment show the code/intellisense breaking, it's reading the '<' as an html tag.

Comment: @user3776749 Am not able to see your images.

Comment: Just try and let me know with hardcoded value  `10<= 10`  instead of your object `item.dueDate <= offSetChoice`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try defining a function inside of your controller with that code and calling that function within ng-hide.

View

```
<div class="rows" ng-init="init(@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))">

    <div class="column" ng-repeat="item in data" ng-hide="someMethod()">

        //display item contents

    </div> 

</div>
```

Controller

```
... // Scope
... // Variables
... // Here
$scope.someMethod = function() {
   return !$scope.displayREI && $scope.item.TaskType === 'REI' || !($scope.item.dueDate <= $scope.offSetChoice);
}
```

Comment: How you get `$scope.item`?